# Macroscopic chromodynamics

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser, quantum-chromodynamics, non-linear-systems

Lately I've been reading about gamma ray lasing phenomena, and I've been wondering about the applications of this.

More concretely, the [above fantastic question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35483/955) led me to wonder if we could somehow collimate the polarization of coherent gamma rays, and radiate hadrons with some resonant chromodynamic frequency (probably very high, but possibly attainable?) that would stimulate excited hadronic states with non-zero color fields of high multipolar rank (quadrupolar or octopular non-zero moments), that at low-energy would thermalize to a high-order aligned macroscopic field?

Comment: Light does not participate in strong interaction.

Comment: @KarsusRen: That's not true--- light participates through quark-pair production, so it mixes with quark condensates at nuclear wavelengths. This is photon-rho mixing which gives the shadow scattering of photons off nuclei. This is discussed very well from both the experimental and theoretical point of view by Kurt Gottfried in 1972 Cornell conference on photon-nucleus scattering, and it is discussed more briefly in Feynman's "Photon Hadron interactions".

Comment: @KarsusRen, quarks have electric charges, so they can be excited electromagnetically

Comment: How do you envisage this "chromodynamic resonant frequency"? The rho Ron is referring in his comment can be that, and possibly all spin one resonances given enough energy of the gamma beam, in this sense this has been demonstrated.